# Find duplicate pairs in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have an array `a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7]`
I want to fetch all the duplicate pair in this array list.
Since there are pairs of 2 and 7 the output should be -

> Output: [2, 7]

I tried writing my own logic but I am very weak in that area. Can somebody help?

```
function getDuplicateArrayElements(arr){
let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort();
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length; i++) {
    let matchingElementCount = 1;

    for (let j = i + 1; j < sorted_arr.length - i; j++) {
        if (sorted_arr[j] === sorted_arr[i]) {
            ++matchingElementCount;          
        } else {
            
            if(matchingElementCount % 2 === 0) {
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
            }
            i = j - 1;
            break;

        }
    }
}
return results; } var a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,6,6,6,7,7]; var duplicateValues= getDuplicateArrayElements(a);
```

Comment: Why no 6 in there?

Comment: Count the number of each value in the array, and then keep only the ones with a count of 2.

Comment: @Viney I think it's because 6 appears 3 times, rather than twice

Comment: But I can have multiple pairs like element 1 repeating 4 times so the output would have [1,1]

Comment: Does the pair have to be consective? Like If there was a `1` at the end, then there'd be four 1's. Is that counted as 2 pairs?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your result by using `reduce` and `forEach`.

```js
const arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7];

// Generate a hashmap from the given array for counting the frequency.
const hashMap = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});


const pair = [];

// If the frequency is divided by 2 then push the key of the hashMap into pair array.
Object.entries(hashMap).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  if (v % 2 === 0) {
    [...Array(Math.floor(v / 2))].forEach(_ => pair.push(k));
  }
})

console.log(pair);
```

Comment: Why you used `([k, v)]` instead of `(k,v)` ?

Comment: `Object.entries()` provides you an array of arrays like `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], ...]`. That's why I've used this way.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin they are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first parameter

Comment: @adiga ,clean answer.

Comment: This only includes items that repeat twice. OP said in the comments: *"the output would have [1,1] if 1 repeates 4 times*"

Comment: According to the OPs comment, you are right @adiga. But I wrote this answer before this comment I think. I will update my answer after the OPs response.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the frequency of each number, and then filter out any which have an odd frequency. You can then `.flatMap()` the frequencies to an array containing your number for each pair you found like so:

```js
const a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7];
const freq = a.reduce((m, n) => m.set(n, (m.get(n) || 0) + 1), new Map);
const res = [...freq].filter(([n, count]) => count % 2 == 0).flatMap(([n, c]) => Array(c/2).fill(n));
console.log(res);
```

This way, if you have four 1s (ie: two pairs of 1s), the filter will pick up on that, allowing you to flat-map the `[1, 4]` array to an array of `[1, 1]`, which is merged into the larger resulting array.

Comment: Are there any benefits of using a `Map` instead of an `Object`? I mean is `map.get` faster than `someObject.somekey`?

Comment: @RameshReddy one advantage in reduce is that `map.set` returns the Map object itself. In case of an object accumulator, you'd have to set the property and return in separate lines or use something like a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for implicit return

Comment: @RameshReddy it might be a little faster, but I haven't tested it. Map works well with reduce as `m.set()` will return the newly modified map which then goes on to be the next value for the accumulator in the next iteration. Using an object also works with reduce, but a for-loop would probably be better for that - but that's debatable (you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg&ab_channel=GoogleChromeDevelopers) video for a little explanation on why I've decided to go with a map here)

Comment: @RameshReddy not just that. `Map` iterates over its contents in order they are inserted. If OP's original array was `[7,7,1,1]`, with an object accumulator, the output would be `[1, 7]` but with a Map it will be `[7, 1]` in the correct order. This is because [integer keys are enumerated in ascending order](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) for objects. Map keeps the order of insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper map and keep the counts of each number as the values and the numbers itself as the keys. After iterating through the array, you only need to find the ones with a count divisible by `2`:

```js
var a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]

function findDuplicates(arr) {

    const map = {};

    for (const curr of arr) {
        if (!map[curr]) {
            map[curr] = 0;
        }
        map[curr]++;
    }
    const res = [];
    for (const key in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key) && map[key] % 2 === 0) {
            res.push(Number.parseInt(key));
        }
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(findDuplicates(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first count the occurrence of each numbers and if it is greater than 0 and divisible by 2 then add these to final result else don't

```js
function getDuplicateArrayElements(arr) {
  let map = {}
  let results = [];

  for (let num of arr) {
    map[num] = map[num] || 0
    map[num]++
  }
  
  return Object.keys(map)
               .filter(v => map[v] && map[v] % 2 === 0)
               .map(v => new Array(map[v]/2).fill(+v))
               .flat()
               .sort()
}

var a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7,8,8,8,8];
var duplicateValues = getDuplicateArrayElements(a);
console.log(duplicateValues)
```

Comment: Wow, you called almost all HOF of Array.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin Hahaha good one, you can drop sort if the output doesn't need to be sorted, map + flat can be replaced by flatMap as done in other answers but doesn't makes much of difference

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = {};
[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,6,6,6,7,7].forEach(v => {a[v] = a[v] ? a[v] + 1 : 1});
const l = [];
Object.keys(a).forEach(k => !(a[k] % 2) && l.push(k));
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another rather concise solution:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7];
uniques = new Set(a); //filter out duplicates
res = [];
uniques.forEach((key)=>{
if(a.filter(elem => elem === key).length === 2){res.push(key)}; 
//filter out only the elements which match the key being tested
//if there are 2, push to result
})
```

Edit: even more concise, but perhaps less efficient:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7];
res = Array.from(new Set(a.filter(elem => a.filter(el => el === elem).length === 2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 function getDuplicateArrayElements(arr){
    var dupilcates=arr.filter(x =>  arr.filter(y=>y==x).length==2);  
    var found=[];
    for(var i=0;i<dupilcates.length;i=i+2)
      found.push(dupilcates[i]);
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired pairs. with `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]` input it will return `[1,1,2,6,6,7]`:

```js
function getDuplicateArrayElements(arr){
  let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort();
  let results = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < sorted_arr.length) {
    let counter = 1;
    let j = i;
    while (sorted_arr[j] === sorted_arr[j+1]) {
      counter++;
      j++;
    }
    
    if (counter%2 == 0) {        
      results.push(...Array(counter/2).fill(sorted_arr[i]))
    }
    
    i += counter;
  }

  return results; 
} 

var a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7];
console.log(getDuplicateArrayElements(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has awesome JSON object, in my opinion, you can use json as a dictionary;

`{ key: _value }`.
Loop throw array one times, no sort, no slice

`key` is array's element value, `_value` is frequency

```
var frequencies = {};
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; a++) {
   if (result[a[i]] == 'over') continue;
   if (result[a[i]] == undefined) { // First times
       result[a[i]] = 1
   } else if (result[a[i]] == 1) { // Second times
       result[a[i]] = 2
   } else { // Ignore if > 2
       result[a[i]] = 'over'
   }
}
// result: {1: "over", 2: 2, 3: "over", 4: "over", 6: "over", 7: 2}
```

so now pick keys have value equal 2

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDuplicateArrayElements(numbers: number[]): number[] {
  const occurences = new Map<number, number>();

  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (occurences.has(number)) {
      const current = occurences.get(number)!;
      occurences.set(number, current + 1);
    } else 
    occurences.set(number, 1)  
  }

  return (
    Array
      .from(occurences.entries())
      .reduce<number[]>(
        (accumulator, [key, value]) => {
          if (value === 2) {
            return accumulator.concat(key)
          }

          return accumulator
        },
        []
      )
  )
}
```

```
const a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7];

getDuplicateArrayElements(a); // [2, 7]
```